# Trigger pipeline when merged in and created new branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have one pipeline created with two stages.

Lets say,

1. Stage A
2. Stage B

I would like to run Stage A when PR is merged into qa branch and run Stage B when release/* or hotfix/* branch is created.

Can this be achieved in one pipeline? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CI trigger:

```
 trigger:
- qa
- releases/*
- hotfix/*
```

Then detect them for each stage: [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages)

```
variables:
  isQA: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/qa')]

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isQA, 'true'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage B!
      - script: echo $(isQA)
```

Check additional conditions: [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#contains)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try out above way